Changing text in ngbcalendar
In the datepicker calendar I use in Angular, the day and month names appear in the component. I want to replace these with the texts I got from the language file. This problem has been solved many times in the app.module.ts file with the help of LOCALEID, there are also examples, but can't I add these texts myself? Is there any way to do this?
The code I use in datepicker:
<div class="input-group">
      <input name="datepicker" class="form-control" ngbDatepicker style="display: none;"
        [footerTemplate]="footerTemplate" #datepicker="ngbDatepicker" [autoClose]="'outside'"
        (dateSelect)="onDateSelection($event)" [displayMonths]="2" [dayTemplate]="t" outsideDays="hidden"
        [startDate]="fromDate!" tabindex="-1">
      <ng-template #t let-date let-focused="focused">
        <span class="custom-day" [class.focused]="focused" [class.range]="isRange(date)"
          [class.faded]="isHovered(date) || isInside(date)" (mouseenter)="hoveredDate = date"
          (mouseleave)="hoveredDate = null">
          {{ date.day }}
        </span>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template #footerTemplate>
        <hr class="my-0">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm m-1 float-left" (click)="selector('today')">{{'text_dashboard_today'|translate}}</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm m-1 float-left" (click)="selector('month')">{{'text_dashboard_this_month'|translate}}</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm m-1 float-left" (click)="selector('year')">{{'text_dashboard_this_year'|translate}}</button>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm m-2 float-right" (click)="datepicker.close()">{{'text_close'|translate}}</button>
      </ng-template>
    </div>

This question has been asked many times, but as a solution, only the localeid in the app.module.ts file has been suggested. I want to intervene directly in the texts.
